# Efficient way to access variable based on index/reference in C#

Tags: c#

Okay, typing the question title I realise I can use an array. However, I'm wondering if there's an alternative in C# for what I'm trying to do.

I have a spreadsheet that denotes upgrades to apply to my game ship. Each entry has four columns that use an int to specify an upgrade type, and another column with an amount to apply, allowing for four out of however many upgrades for each item.

Thus in my 'hull' spreadsheet I have upgd_1_type, upgd_2_type, upgd_3_type, upgd_4_type, which refer to one of seven upgrade types, and updg_1_amnt etc. for how much to apply.

I've just entered the below code which is a honking great switch statement with lots of horribly duplicated code, which got me wondering if there's a better way to do things.

```
    void GetHullUpgradeVals(GDEHullData hullDat){
    switch(hullDat.upgd_1_type){
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.COST:
            upg_Hull_cost *= 1/hullDat.upgd_1_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.IMPACT_RES:
            upg_Hull_impactRes *= hullDat.upgd_1_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.MASS:
            upg_Hull_mass *= 1/hullDat.upgd_1_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.MAX_HEALTH:
            upg_Hull_mxhlth *= hullDat.upgd_1_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.PICK_RAD:
            upg_Hull_pickRad *= hullDat.upgd_1_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.REGEN:
            upg_Hull_regen *= hullDat.upgd_1_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.PICK_RAD:
            upg_Hull_pickRad *= hullDat.upgd_1_amnt; break;
    }
    switch(hullDat.upgd_2_type){
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.COST:
            upg_Hull_cost *= 1/hullDat.upgd_2_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.IMPACT_RES:
            upg_Hull_impactRes *= hullDat.upgd_2_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.MASS:
            upg_Hull_mass *= 1/hullDat.upgd_2_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.MAX_HEALTH:
            upg_Hull_mxhlth *= hullDat.upgd_2_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.PICK_RAD:
            upg_Hull_pickRad *= hullDat.upgd_2_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.REGEN:
            upg_Hull_regen *= hullDat.upgd_2_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.PICK_RAD:
            upg_Hull_pickRad *= hullDat.upgd_2_amnt; break;
    }
    switch(hullDat.upgd_3_type){
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.COST:
            upg_Hull_cost *= 1/hullDat.upgd_3_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.IMPACT_RES:
            upg_Hull_impactRes *= hullDat.upgd_3_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.MASS:
            upg_Hull_mass *= 1/hullDat.upgd_3_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.MAX_HEALTH:
            upg_Hull_mxhlth *= hullDat.upgd_3_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.PICK_RAD:
            upg_Hull_pickRad *= hullDat.upgd_3_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.REGEN:
            upg_Hull_regen *= hullDat.upgd_3_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.PICK_RAD:
            upg_Hull_pickRad *= hullDat.upgd_3_amnt; break;
    }
    switch(hullDat.upgd_4_type){
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.COST:
            upg_Hull_cost *= 1/hullDat.upgd_4_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.IMPACT_RES:
            upg_Hull_impactRes *= hullDat.upgd_4_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.MASS:
            upg_Hull_mass *= 1/hullDat.upgd_4_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.MAX_HEALTH:
            upg_Hull_mxhlth *= hullDat.upgd_4_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.PICK_RAD:
            upg_Hull_pickRad *= hullDat.upgd_4_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.REGEN:
            upg_Hull_regen *= hullDat.upgd_4_amnt; break;
        case (int)UPGRADES_HULL.PICK_RAD:
            upg_Hull_pickRad *= hullDat.upgd_4_amnt; break;
    }
}
```

I'll swap out my seven individual variables with an array of seven and reference by index, but is there a way to select a variable based on an index? Something like pointers to give a new variable a reference to another variable? Any other clever solutions?

Edit : Using array

```
    void GetHullUpgradeVals(GDEHullData hullDat){
    upgs_Hull[hullDat.upgd_1_type] = hullDat.upgd_1_amnt;
    upgs_Hull[hullDat.upgd_2_type] = hullDat.upgd_2_amnt;
    upgs_Hull[hullDat.upgd_3_type] = hullDat.upgd_3_amnt;
    upgs_Hull[hullDat.upgd_4_type] = hullDat.upgd_4_amnt;

    upgs_Hull[(int)UPGRADES_HULL.COST] = 1/upgs_Hull[(int)UPGRADES_HULL.COST];
    upgs_Hull[(int)UPGRADES_HULL.MASS] = 1/upgs_Hull[(int)UPGRADES_HULL.MASS];
}
```

Comment: Yes it is called reflection. You may use attributes on each prop to add extra info for reflection. Google reflection. But it makes your program run slower

Comment: You _could_ use Reflection, but doing so would greatly decrease performance and isn't recommended in situations like this. Using an array or a lookup table is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know more elegant solutions.

Hi David, again!

You can create custom variables. It will be reference variable. hm...

For example:

```
public class IntVariable{
    public int Value;
    public void DivideAndMultiply(){ // for example some method we can create
        Value *= 1 / Value;
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
IntVariable upg_Hull_cost;
IntVariable upg_Hull_impactRes;
//.....

IntVariable GetVariable(UpgradeType type) {
    switch(type) {
        case UpgradeType.COST:
            return upg_Hull_cost;
        case UpgradeType.IMPACT_RES:
            return upg_Hull_impactRes;
            //....
    }
    return null;
}
///...
void GetHullUpgradeVals(GDEHullData hullDat){
     GetVariable(hullDat.upgd_1_type).Value = hullDat.upgd_1_amnt;
     GetVariable(hullDat.upgd_2_type).Value = hullDat.upgd_2_amnt;
     //...
     GetVariable(UPGRADES_HULL.COST).DivideAndMultiply();
}
```

Hope this will help you in looking for other solutions.

You can use `ScriptableObjects` in your game for Data Base, items, upgrades, AI and etc.